# My integrated terminal window is often blank when I compile with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, compilation, ubuntu-20.04

I've started using VS code to compile code but I have a lot of problems since the terminal with the compilation logs is often blank without reason. Sometimes I get the logs and so I can see if the compilation succeeded or failed but it happens quite often the terminal window stays blank so I have to re-launch it...

It's really tedious and I don't know how to fix this...

I compile C++ with Cmake and I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Any ideas ?

Thx!

Comment: At a guess you're using the cmake plugin and attempting to do more than one operation at once, the second operation erases the terminal output of the first. The solution is to only do one thing at a time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.